# How to optimze throughput for REST API calls in an akka-stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm currently learning about akka streams and I'm trying to implement a simple stream that gets an item from a source and calls a 
REST api for every item.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```scala
source.mapAsync(parallelism){ item =>
    Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, "http://myserver:8080/$item"))
        .flatMap(response => response.entity.toStrict(20.seconds))
}
```

I'm wondering now how to set `parallelism` to get maximal throughput if the bottleneck is the REST server.

My understanding is that if we assume that the server cannot handle request in parallel, I could use `parallelism = 1` as first approximation
and my stream would send one request after another. 
If the server can handle `n` requests in parallel, the stream wouldn't utilize that and I would have to set `parallelism = n` to get a
better throughput.

I could now play around with `parallelism` to optimize throughput for my setup at a given point in time.
However, myserver could be behind a load balancer and an auto-scaler. Then the number of parallel requests available to the stream would depend on the time
and maybe my program is not the only user of the REST API.

My question is now, what would be the best approach for calling the REST API when I want to utilize myserver as good as possible but
don't want to overwhelm it if it is under pressure or not yet scaled up?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is kind of built-in for streams, since they are utilizing backpressure. So as soon as the rest server is at its limits, answers will take longer and your stream will then request fewer requests from the source. So you actually do not need to optimize your parallelism for a current state of the requested server, but tune it for good throughput. For any requested server, this will only be as fast as ur requested server is able to answer.
With a similar Graph ure using above, I was able to bring a cluster of 2 nodes to its limits as well as 16 nodes with scaling-up built into the cluster, so the Graph worked cleanly for both states, only the throughput inceeased significantly :).

You should be off well by setting the level of parallelism to the number of cores your machine utilizes.

You can also use a `.throttle(...)` on your source to set the maximal number of requests you want to provide per time unit.

In case you dynamically want to react to the maximal number of requests you get answered by the service and then lets say limit yourself to 80% of that, youd have to code some custom for it I think. For example a Flow Stage which counts requests for some time, then throttles accordingly, and does this again some time later in case service scaled up and so on. But finally handling of requests per user should be at the level of the requested service.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more "optimal" way to make the requests than demonstrated in the question.

If you use the [connection level client-side api](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/connection-level.html) then you can open a connection pool to the service that you are interested in:

```
val connectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] =
  Http().outgoingConnection("http://myserver:8080")
```

This pool can then be used to process your `item` requests:

```
type Item = ???

val itemToRequest : Item => HttpRequest = 
  item => HttpRequest(uri = URI(item.toString))

source
  .map(itemToRequest)
  .via(connectionFlow)
  .flatMap(_.entity.toStrict(20.seconds))
```

You can then use [the akka configuration settings](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html) to specify the maximum number of open requests to `myserver`:

```
host-connection-pool {
  max-open-requests = 8
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html#future-based-variant) says about `singleRequest`: `Internally the request is dispatched across the (cached) host connection pool for the request’s effective URI.` To send more items to the server I also have to manage the `max-open-requests`.

Answer (score -3):

So the method `mapAsync(parallelism)` belongs to `object source` and you have a few nested functions - let's make this a few simpler functions instead of one big nested one and it should be optimized.